# RegEx - skip text between quotes

Tags: regex

how can I skip some text which is between **quotes("text")** or **brackets(<div>text<div>)** or anything else

here is an **example** where I have a **Django template** and I want to find the **tags**, where I have intentionally injected tags inside a string.

```
{% load humanize %}

{% url "core:p%}os{%t" post.pk %}  {% url "index" %}
```

and this is the regex currently I have

```
\{%\s*\b(url|load)\b.*?\s*%\}
```

What this regex matches is

> `{% url "core:p%}`

But obviously that is not what I want. I want to match the whole tag like this

> `{% url "core:p%}os{%t" post.pk %}`

Here is the regexer [link](https://regexr.com/6hb0c), where you can test it.

Comment: `^(\{\%\s(load|url)\s)(?:\'.*\')?(.*$)` perhaps? You'd then just extract capture groups `\1` and `\3` to get what you want.

Comment: Check the edited question

Comment: Jeffrey Friedl devotes quite a number of pages in his book to this topic. Are you really sure you want to use regular expressions? Then probably search before asking.